# Firebase Xcode error:cannot load module 'firebaseDatabase' as 'FirebaseDatabase'

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, firebase-realtime-database

i use cocoapods install the Firbase/Database to my project.
and i don't write any code into my project.
but when i run my project, this red error happen.
i want to know how to fix it,help me please.

Answer (score 0):

cause i build a project named 'firebaseDatabase',then this problem happen,still don't know why.